# Deadlock on parallel loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, locking, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize the code below. It's easy to see that there is a dependency between the values of `aux`, since they are computed after the inner loop, but they are needed inside that inner loop (note that on the first iteration j = 0, the code inside the inner loop is not executed). On the other hand, there is no dependency between the values of mu because we only update `mu[k]`, but the only values needed for other computations are in `mu[j]`, for `0 <= j < k`.

My approach consists in having the elements of `aux` locked until they are computed. As soon as a given value of `aux` is computed, the lock of that element is released and every thread can use it. However, with this code a deadlock occurs and I can't figure out why. Does someone have any tips?

Thanks

```
for (j = 0; j < k; ++j)
    locks[j] = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N_THREADS) private(j, i)
for (j = 0; j < k; ++j)
{
  vals[j] = (long)0;

  for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
  {
    while(!locks[i]);
    vals[j] += mu[j][i] * aux[i];
  }

  aux[j] = (s[j] - vals[j]);
  locks[j] = 1;

  mu[k][j] = aux[j] / c[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it also hang when not optimized?
In optimized code, gcc would not bother reading `locks[i]` more than once, so this:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  while(!locks[i]);
```

would be like writing:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  if( !locks[i] ) for(;;) {}
```

Try adding a barrier to force gcc to re-read locks[i]:

```
#define pause() do { asm volatile("pause;":::"memory"); } while(0)
...

  for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    while(!locks[i]) pause();
```

HTH